# Define Model in 2 DbContexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 `DbContexts`, one manages `IdentityUser` and other models
The class `MyUser` has one to one relation with `ApplicationUser`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual MyUser  MyUser { get; set; }

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<MyUser> MyUsers { get; set; }
}
```

In the model project, i have a class called `Review` where review has many to one with `MyUser`

```
 public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MyUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual MyUser MyUser { get; set; }
}


public class MyUser
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    }

public class MyContext: DbContext
    {
        public MyContext() :
            base(nameOrConnectionString: "DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set;}

        // Do i have to add MyUser DebSet here?

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

My question is, MyUser should be linked to Reviews and to `ApplicationUser`
Reviews are defiened in `MyContext` and `ApplicationUser` is defiened in `ApplicationDbContext`

How can i write the relations? in whitch DbContext , any idea?

Comment: You can't.  You have to have all entities referenced by other entities in the same context.  Which means you would have to have a copy of Reviews in both contexts